# 400 bad request the request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax postman tool error

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, postman

I am doing the **POST** operation from Postman tool to SharePoint online list but getting the **400 bad request the request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax** error.

Here are my configuration in Postman tool:

**URL:**

https://globalsharepoint2019.sharepoint.com/sites/SharePointRND/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('TestList')/Items

**Raw Request Body:**

[image: Raw request body]

**Headers Parameters:**

[image: Headers Parameters]

**POST request status: 400 bad request the request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax**

[image: 400 bad request the request]

Anyone could help me - what is the bad syntax error here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to include the "__metadata" object in your POST, you need to specify your content-type as "application/json;odata=verbose".

Alternatively, if you need to use the "application/json;odata=minimalmetadata" content-type, remove the whole "__metadata" json object, and instead specify the "ContentTypeId" in your body just like you are doing for your "Title", but you would need to first look up the ID of your `TestListListItem` ContentType.